# The provider is not compatible with the version of oracle (ASP.NET Core MVC)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm really frustrated and i do not know what to do.

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle 11g database but every time I try to connect Visual Studio 2019 throws an error message. I already tried a lot of different things but nothing really helped me.

I have already made sure the app set to run in 32 bit mode in the IIS console. I still can't figure out why is not working.

By the way, here is my code:

```
readonly string connectionString = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxxxxxxx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=PROD)));User Id=xxx;Password=xxxx;"

public IEnumerable<Person>GetPersonList
{
    var listPerson = new List<Person>();

    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from myview", con);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.InitialLOBFetchSize = 1000;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        con.Open();

        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            var list = new Person();
            list.CODE = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CODE"].ToString());
            list.NAME = dr["NAME"].ToString();
            list.LASTNAME = dr["LASTNAME"].ToString();

            listPerson.Add(list);
        }

        con.Close();
    }

    return listPerson;
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is the version of oracle client and .net core or .net framework?

Comment: Hey pal, thanks for replying. How do i know if i have installed any oracle client? Can i install it directly through Visual Studio? The ASP.NET MVC Cre is 5.0

Comment: are you using oracle client or ado.net? Oracle has provided [ODP.net for .net core.]( https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/ODPNET_Core_get_started/index.html)

Comment: Pal, i'm a little confused: do i need to download the oracle client from Oracle page or is it the same to install a plugin in Visual Studio?

Comment: no the nuget package you need odp.net

Comment: Dude, alright. Just a question: i havent downloaded any Oracle Client, my question is if i can download some nuget package instead

Comment: The nuget package will work. You don't need to install it explicitly. One question how are you accessing the database from your system?

Comment: Thanks for replaying. I have installed these nuget packages:
**odac.cleit.x64**, **ODAC.x86.11g**, **Oracle.DataAccess.x86**, **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess**. It stills is telling me that "The provider is not compatible with the version of oracle" :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved: needed to install instant client for Oracle 11g and everything worked just fine